# How to Get Parameters from URL using .htaccess in PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I show following URL using .htaccess re-write rule with a non ? parameter?

```
Original URL
http://example.com/index.php?store=1

Desired URL 
http://example.com/1/
```

OR

```
Desired URL 
http://example.com/store/1
```

I am trying following code in .htaccess. What I am missing here?

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriteRule ^store/(.+)\$ index.php?store=$1 [L]
```

my index.php file has this code

```
<?php
$storeid = $_GET['store'];
echo $storeid;
?>
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping your end-of-string character, causing the expression to look for a literal `$` sign so it never matches.

You need something like:

```
rewriteRule ^store/(.+)$ /index.php?store=$1 [L]
                       ^ no back-slash here
```

or if you want to make sure you only match numbers:

```
rewriteRule ^store/(\d+)$ /index.php?store=$1 [L]
```